# XML Comments - How to comment multiple reasons for an exception?

Tags: exception, xml-comments

Here's an example:

```
public void DoSomething(String param1, String param2)
{
    if (param1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("param1");
    if (param2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("param2");
}
```

2 different reasons for an ArgumentNullException. MSDNs [String.Format Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) shows 2 different reasons for the `FormatException`. So, is it done this way:

```
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
///     <paramref name="param1"/> is null.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
///     <paramref name="param2"/> is null.
/// </exception>
```

or some other way?

```
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
///     Some other way to show the 2 reasons with an "-or-" between them.
/// </exception>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you think each of the rows of the docs as being one `<exception cref=...> </exception>`, then logically the correct way to do it is using your second alternative:

```
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
///     <p><paramref name="param1"/> is null. </p>
///     <p>- or - </p>
///     <p><paramref name="param2"/> is null. </p>
/// </exception>
```

You can use 'p' elements to denote the lines.

Comment: I actually ended up using that, but it seemed to be that there should be a better way to do this. Oh well. Also, <para></para> should be used instead of <p></p>. They're equal, but considering that <para> is recognized by intellisense, I think it's preferred.

Comment: I think that doubling the `<exception cref=...>`, would be the same as doubling the table rows present in the documentation. For sure, the `para` tag is much better.